# How do I unescape HTML tags from XML?

Tags: html, ruby, xml, api, parsing

I am using Ruby 1.8.7 and have XML content as a string which is the API response. I want to parse this response so that I can unescape the HTML tags:

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<response>\n  <data>\n    <publisher_share_percent>0.0</publisher_share_percent>\n    <detailed_description>&lt;b&gt;this is the testing detailed&lt;/b&gt; </detailed_description>\n   <title>Only &#163;5.00. food (Regular &#163;50.00 / 90% discount)</title>\n  </data>\n  <request_id>ed96dd50-3127-012f-3e93-042b2b8686e6</request_id>\n  <message>The resource has been created successfully.</message>\n  <status>201</status>\n</response>\n
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [CGI::unescapeHTML](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/cgi/rdoc/CGI.html#method-c-unescapeHTML).

```
require 'cgi'
CGI::unescapeHTML("Usage: foo &quot;bar&quot; &lt;baz&gt;")
# => "Usage: foo \"bar\" <baz>"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you treat the XML as what it is, XML, and parse it using an XML parser, the task gets easier:

```
require 'nokogiri'

xml = <<EOT
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
  <data>
    <publisher_share_percent>0.0</publisher_share_percent>
    <detailed_description>&lt;b&gt;this is the testing detailed&lt;/b&gt; </detailed_description>
   <title>Only &#163;5.00. food (Regular &#163;50.00 / 90% discount)</title>
  </data>
  <request_id>ed96dd50-3127-012f-3e93-042b2b8686e6</request_id>
  <message>The resource has been created successfully.</message>
  <status>201</status>
  </response>
EOT

doc = Nokogiri::XML(xml)
puts doc.at('detailed_description').text
puts doc.at('title').text
```

Saving and running the file outputs:

```
ruby ~/Desktop/test2.rb 
<b>this is the testing detailed</b> 
Only £5.00. food (Regular £50.00 / 90% discount)
```